# TCP send a packet with External IP Source?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, pcap.net

i will creat a valid TCP Packet (3 way handshake) to request on my server (real server online not vmware localhost)

```
My PC IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.4
My ONLINE IP ADDRESS: 177.9.9.9 
My Server IP ADDRESS: 113.x.x.x
```

I send a TCP Packet from my PC (177.9.9.9) to server (113.x.x.x) and success! 
I can see this request showing in Wireshrak very clear with source IP is 177.9.9.9 and Destination ip is 113.x.x.x

i will write packet in C# with PCAP.NET and here is my ipV4Layer code!

```
IpV4Layer ipV4Layer =
    new IpV4Layer
    {
        Source = new IpV4Address("192.168.1.4"), // My lan IP address
        CurrentDestination = new IpV4Address("113.x.x.x"), // Server IP ADDRESS
        HeaderChecksum = null, // Will be filled automatically.
        Identification = 28104,
        Options = IpV4Options.None,
        Protocol = null, // Will be filled automatically.
        Ttl = 128,
        TypeOfService = 0,
    };
```

NOW i want to ask, how to change 177.9.9.9 to another IP address? Not Proxy, Not socks, NOT VPN! I want to change my online IP to any IP ADDRESS, i just want to send a TCP SYN request like this and don't need server response any data, just send it with any IP address, how can do that or this way is Impossible?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Of course it's possible but it's not exactly a friendly thing to be doing because you'll be causing the server to send packets to some other location that's not expecting it. That's generally termed an attack and it's not something I'd choose to help someone else to do.

Comment: This question has the potential for controversy.  You shouldn't be masking or hiding your ip address this way.  If it's allowed for FTP, which I'm sure most firewalls check for this sort of thing, it's as 'Damien_The_Unbeliever' said.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for help me to know is possible, i don't want to attack anyone, i have an ideal for my server can using in load balancing and take some effect in group server

Comment: @Justin Russo yeb, i know but i don't want to use Proxy, Socks or any mask, i want more deep in TCP system and creat a real packet with new source IP Adress i can make it. Thanks for comment

Comment: you need to explain in more detail what you want to do. You suggestion is wrong in every way, the only scenario where i can imagine this used is in some sort of DoS attack, which is illegal in most countries.

Comment: I know don't have anyone can help me to do this, but anybody can suggestion me for this? I never creat any topic like that, OMG!!!

Comment: No one is going to assist you on StackOverflow in something that can potentially affect their careers as legitimate engineers, and assist in potentially illegal activity.  Your reasons for what you want are not clear enough for us to justly understand WHY you need this other than to possibly establish some form of illegal activity, including the potential distribution of child porn.  You may want to look up your question on Google.  I'm sure there are plenty of hackers who live in their parent's basement, and don't care about their reputation, who may be willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do some sort of load balancing then, go google the concept and research the viable options.

Here are some examples:

- DNS based
- Router/firewall/nat
- Servicebus with queues, for a high level solution

Comment: Can change source IP if i config nat of router?

Comment: you source ip is decided by your ISP, they can reassign you a new ip or assign a pool of ips for you to use.